# Как трансформировать поток из Write в Read (NODE JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, потоки-данных

Задача такая, что мы выкачиваем файл с помощью request и далее отправляем этот файл на какой-то API (этот API принимает поток чтения - ReadStream).
в текущий момент реализация выглядит грубо говоря так:
(не устраивает, то что нужно создавать временный файл)

```js
 request(audioLink)
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./source/${fileName}`))
            .on('close', function () {
                ctx.replyWithVoice({
                    source: fs.createReadStream(`./source/${fileName}`)
                })
            })
```

т.е нам приходится пайпить в поток записи и по завершению создавать поток чтение, который мы передаем в другой метод (API).
Как можно реализовать подобное, но при этом не создавая этот временный файл файл?
Я наверное сейчас покажусь невероятным глупцом, но разве нельзя request трансформировать в поток чтение, что бы не создавать временный файл и сразу вызвать APi метод передав ему напрямую данные из request (повтороюсь, что API метод принимает ReadStream)

Comment: Что делает функция `ctx.replyWithVoice`? Какие параметры она принимает и откуда она? Думаю, что в указанном коде работа с потоками не рациональна, т.к. мы не перенаправляем поток, а сохраняем данные в файл, дожидаемся окончания записи и только потом передаем содержимое файла в функцию `replyWithVoice`. Если функция `replyWithVoice` принимает не только Stream, то можно попробовать без потоков `request(audioLink, function(error, response, body) { ctx.replyWithVoice({ source: body }); })`

Comment: @СтаниславГро это API для бота (telegram) она принимает Buffer или ReadStream, как и говорилось выше, задача такая, что нужно получить аудио, прогнать его через ffmpeg и отправить результат через ctx.replyWithVoice, могу реализовать это создавая куча временных файлов, но мне кажется, что можно как-то и без них.

Answer (score 0):

Пример с `Buffer`

```
request({
  url: audioLink,
  encoding: null 
}, function (err, response, responseBody) {
  // TODO need handle error
  ctx.replyWithVoice({
    source: responseBody
  });
})
```

`responseBody` может быть 3-х типов: `Buffer`, `String`, `Object` (json data)

мы указали параметр `encoding` как `null`, чтобы тип `responseBody` был `Buffer`, а т.к. функция `replyWithVoice` может принимать тип `Buffer`, то таким образом мы минуем работу с потоками